# How to use different contour levels for different functions

Tags: gnuplot

I need to contour plot 3 different functions with gnuplot, but for 2 of them, I just need the contour level 0, for the other, I need the levels 10, 12 and 14. This is what I got so far:

```
f(x,y) = 10 + x + y
g1(x, y) = 5 - x - 2*y
g2(x, y) = (1/x) + (1/y) - 2
set contour base
set isosample 250, 250
set cntrparam cubicspline
unset surface
set size square
set view map
set yrange[-1:5]
set xrange[-1:5]

set cntrparam levels discrete 0
splot f(x,y), g2(x,y), g1(x,y)
```

[image: plot]

The problem is that I can either use:

```
set cntrparam levels discrete 0
```

or

```
set cntrparam levels discrete 10, 12, 14
```

for all the functions, but I don't know how to use the former for `g1(x,y)` and `g2(x,y)` only, while using the later for `f(x,y)`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot define different contour settings for different functions which are to be plotted together. In your case there is a workaround, since the contour levels are well separated from each other. You must define your functions to be `1/0` where the unwanted levels are. Here I choose 5 as limit, which is in the middle:

```
f(x,y) = 10 + x + y
g1(x, y) = 5 - x - 2*y
g2(x, y) = (1/x) + (1/y) - 2
set contour base
set isosample 250, 250
set cntrparam cubicspline
unset surface
set size square
set view map
set yrange[-1:5]
set xrange[-1:5]

set cntrparam levels discrete 0, 10, 12, 14

splot (f(x,y) > 5 ? f(x,y) : 1/0) t 'f(x,y)', \
      (g2(x,y) < 5 ? g2(x,y) : 1/0) t 'g2(x,y)', \
      (g1(x,y) < 5 ? g1(x,y) : 1/0) t 'g1(x,y)'
```

The result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]